DNS Log Rollover doesn't works
I set up debug logging of dns in a Domain Controller on Windows Server 2019 in the following way:

I enabled log rollover with the powershell string:
Set-DnsServerDiagnostics -EnableLogFileRollover $true

What happens is that the file is correctly created with the date nomenclature but once the size limit is reached, another file is not created and it crashes.

An event log should have been created, what crashes exactly, the entire server?

@Ramhound An event log is created but when it reaches the maximum size, another rotation log is not created.
In other Domain Controller in which it is activated with the same configurations these are created correctly

Separate domain or same domain?

@Ramhound same domain

If it's the same domain, I assume you have adopted this new controller, which has a backup of the primary. Wouldn't the logs from whichever server is the primary at any given time be the logs you are worried about? I am still not sure "what exactly crashes" to be honest

Check output of Get-DnsServerDiagnostics and confirm it looks good size wise. Ensure after you make the changes to restart the DNS server i.e. Restart-Service -Name DNS. If there are still issues, set the log file size to a smaller size like 5-20 MB and then restart the DNS service, and then see if it's working as expected at a smaller file size. I'll assume "C" drive disk space is not an issue, but something to check just in case. Consider renaming the log file if you stop the DNS service, then see if it builds a new one with appropriate name once set and restarting the DNS service.
